# how to tell "gmake" to use another version of GCC? (Linux)

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, gnu-make

I have the usual gcc on my machine (at /usr/bin/gcc), and another one (newer) is linked when I setup the environment for a certain framework which I'm working on.

And I would like to compile with the old one I have on /usr/bin/gcc, instead of using the newer one.

I have to use "gmake" command for the compilation (custom compilation setup).

Without changing the PATH, how could I "tell" gmake to use a different gcc?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not try your suggestions, because our compilation-framework does not allow me to change the GCC (and the makefile is built dinamically). And I discovered that I cannot compile with a different gcc because the framework has to be compiled with a specific one. But thanks a lot for your answers anyway! :-) I hope they will can help somebody else. +1 to all of you for your kind help!! :-))

Answer (score 11):

from command line:
`gmake CC=/usr/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
make CC=/opt/bin/my-gcc
```

And make sure that for compilation you use $(CC) instead of direct gcc:

```
foo.o: foo.c
          $(CC) -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

If you use default compilation patters the gmake uses CC variable by default

Answer (score 2):

In your makefile, define a variable for your preferred compiler.

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
```

And after your target, use the variable.

```
a.o : a.c
    $(CC) ...
```